# SolR Query - Price ranges

Tags: lucene, solr, slider, search-engine

I'm querying SolR server to get the *price* ranges.

How can I construct a query which returns at once:

- price range for all of the items (without facet query)
- price range (or list) for items with facet query

I need these four values for a slider like this:

```
all_min=============user_min========user_max========all_max
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [StatsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent) to get min and max. Use [facet.range](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Facet_by_Range) or [facet.query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.query_%3a_Arbitrary_Query_Faceting) to get facets on specific price ranges.

Comment: StatsComponent is great, but can I use it on each group of my Result Grouping ? I would like the price range of each group. How can I do it ?

Comment: @Bob Yoplait: please create another question.

Comment: OK, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255696/solr-dynamic-price-ranges-and-groups