# Solr dynamic price ranges and groups

Tags: solr

Following up on questions

- [How to get facet ranges in solr results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956/how-to-get-facet-ranges-in-solr-results)
- [SolR Query - Price ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241960/solr-query-price-ranges)

if I understand correctly, to get the number of matches per price intervals in Solr, here are the different ways one can use:

- per static price intervals:

  - facet.range
  - facet.query
- per dynamic price intervals

  - there is Solr JIRA to get dynamic facet intervals:[Solr JIRA 1581: Facet by function](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1581)

To get only price min and price max:

- for the field "price" on the whole index: StatsComponent

Now my question is: I can get result grouping work OK, but how to get price min and max on each group (&group=true). Is there a Solr JIRA associated with it ?

[Lucene JIRA 3097: Post group faceting does](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3097) presents results in global facets and not in "per group" results.

Answer (score 0):

Solr version: 5.4 and above.

I have a solution for this and I have implemented in my project.

You have to use json facet to achive the max and min value based on the facet result.

```
    json.facet={
   tags_group:{
      type:terms,
      field:tags,
      limit:-1,
      facet:{
         pricemin:{
            type:terms,
            field:price,
            limit:1,
            sort:{
               x:asc
            },
            facet:{
               x:"min(price)"
            }
         },
         pricemax:{
            type:terms,
            field:price,
            limit:1,
            sort:{
               y:desc
            },
            facet:{
               y:"max(price)"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In the above Json facet I have used tags as filed(multivalued) and this will create a bucket like this

```
<str name="val">Letter Holder</str>
<int name="count">2</int>
<lst name="pricemin">
    <arr name="buckets">
        <lst>
            <double name="val">899.0</double>
            <int name="count">1</int>
            <double name="x">899.0</double>
        </lst>
    </arr>
</lst>
<lst name="pricemax">
    <arr name="buckets">
        <lst>
            <double name="val">1299.0</double>
            <int name="count">1</int>
            <double name="y">1299.0</double>
        </lst>
    </arr>
</lst>
```